# I want to use hidden markov model for data prediction

Tags: tensorflow, hidden-markov-models, tensorflow-probability

I am new to machine learning models and data science libraries. I wanted to use the Hidden Markov model for statistical data prediction on the fly which read the data from kafka and builds the model which is used to predict the data during the run-time and do the same for continous stream always.

Currently i can see only Tensorflow hidden markov model implementation in tensorflow python (tensorflow_probability distribution). Is their any other library available which can help me acheive the above scenario

Suggestions can involve the libraries of JAVA and python

Please feel free to add any resource links that can help me to understand the usage of tensorflow for hidden markov model

Answer (score 1):

this might be a nice place to start: https://hmmlearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Other alternatives, I found, are

Java:
[Mallet library](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/) and it's extention [GRMM](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/grmm/index.php) in particular.

Python:
[Pommegranate](https://pomegranate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with it's [HMM support](https://pomegranate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HiddenMarkovModel.html).

Having said that, TensorFlow is much better known active and supported library, in my impression. I'd try that first.

I'm searching a library that would support Hierarchical HMMs (HHMM). That would probably require some tweaking into one of the listed ones.